# Problems with TemperatureSetting trait schema and 'auto' mode

Tags: google-smart-home, google-assist-api

I've been developed and got released a Google smart home device using the Thermostat device and ThermostatSetting trait schema. The modes defined are: "off", "on", "heat", "cool", "auto"

For some reason, Google Home on both iOS and Android won't show the 'auto' mode anymore, but displays it as 'other'. I know for sure, that 'auto' was supported in Google Home a couple of months ago.

SYNC example:

```
{
  "requestId": "1837210953134681851",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "1518": {
        "online": true,
        "thermostatTemperatureSetpoint": 10,
        "thermostatMode": "auto",
        "thermostatHumidityAmbient": 20.01,
        "thermostatTemperatureAmbient": 10.01
      }
    }
  }
}
```

QUERY example:

```
{
  "requestId": "10672456171400406265",
  "payload": {
    "agentUserId": "b8c128c8-922d-477b-830b-b86314d810be",
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": "1518",
        "type": "action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
        ],
        "name": {
          "defaultNames": [
            "Fisk"
          ],
          "name": "Fisk",
          "nicknames": [
            "Fisk"
          ]
        },
        "willReportState": true,
        "deviceInfo": {
          "manufacturer": "BITZER",
          "model": "LMC 311",
          "hwVersion": "1.0",
          "swVersion": "2.4.0"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C",
          "availableThermostatModes": "off,on,heat,cool,auto"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "515",
        "type": "action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
        ],
        "name": {
          "defaultNames": [
            "Ventilation system 20"
          ],
          "name": "Ventilation system 20",
          "nicknames": [
            "Ventilation system 20"
          ]
        },
        "willReportState": true,
        "deviceInfo": {
          "manufacturer": "BITZER",
          "model": "Comfort CT150",
          "hwVersion": "1.0",
          "swVersion": "2.4.14.0"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "thermostatTemperatureUnit": "C",
          "availableThermostatModes": "off,on,heat,cool,auto"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Picture of google home (its in Danish - 'Anden' is translated to 'Other'):
[Google Home 'auto' mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lugaq.jpg)

Anyone experience the same problem or perhaps knows the root cause ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the SYNC, QUERY responses sent by your device and the output you are seeing on Assistant surfaces (e.g. mobile, smart display).

Comment: Updated original post with the examples.

Comment: Seems like the QUERY and SYNC intent are swapped, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I just saw the same problem. The "auto" & "on" mode shows the "other" mode on Android. On iPhone, it shows nothing. Really weird.

Comment: Got news from a Google developer a week ago - he'll try and reproduce (~6 months later!!)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been filed in the public bug tracker and is being resolved there. You can find more information about the issue and the debugging information at https://issuetracker.google.com/157717871